# click link with particular text in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried a few things such as this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Selenium");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bladibla.com");

ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
{
    if (element.Text.Equals("Bla"))
    {

    }
    Console.WriteLine(element.Text);
}
```

Including some XPath without success. All I want is click the link represented by this html:

```
<a href="xyz/bla.txt" onclick="ga('send', 'pageview', 'xyz/bla.txt');"><img src="images/download16.png" alt="Download XYZ" />Bla</a>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

PS:

Current code:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace Selenium
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Selenium");
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php?Search=AB1");

                var test = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href^='UKPostcodesKML']"));

                driver.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `FindElements` is not finding the link you are looking for, it is possible the link you are trying to find is contained within a `<frame>` or `<iframe>`.

Comment: @Richard - thanks. I cannot see any iframes. The site is: http://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php?Search=AB1 and I want to click: 'Download the individual postcode data in KML format (for use in Google Earth)'.

Comment: What browser and version are you using?  What version of Selenium?  If Chrome or IE, what version of the driver.exe?

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 m. This is what my chrome driver says: Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 9515

Comment: I'm pretty sure ChromeDriver 2.9 does not support Chrome 40.  I'd suggest updating to latest Selenium and ChromeDriver, and retest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial link text like below.

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Bla"))
```

or

if the href is unique for that anchor, then you can get that specific anchor by using css selector like below.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href=xyz/bla.txt]")
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work - in fact get an exception as partialLinkText is not found. I added a comment to my question which indicates the site I am targeting ...

Comment: Is it always the third link that you want to click or you are looking for a generic example of how to click a link with specific text?

Comment: Try this. Since i can only one link with a href that begins with UKPostcodesKML. This will break if the href values changes. So just a caution around that. It just finds an anchor whose href value begins with "UKPostcodesKML" . Hope this helps. `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href^='UKPostcodesKML'])`

Comment: Thanks. I tried: driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href^='UKPostcodesKML']")) but OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Would you mind posting block of code where you are doing this operation. There is something in your code which i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'KML format')]")).click();
```

Or this:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("KML format")).click();
```

Comment: sorry OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException